# Showing $ \int_0^{2\pi} f(e^{it}) e^{it} dt =0$ for holomoprhic function $f$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration

Let $U\subseteq \mathbb{C}$ be an open set. Suppose that $U\supseteq \{ e^{it} : 0 \leq t <2\pi \}$. Let $f$ be a holomorphic function on $U$ which has a holomorphic antiderivative. then we have
\begin{align}
  \int_0^{2\pi} f(e^{it}) e^{it} dt =0
\end{align}

I have no clue for this, can you give me some proof or brief idea for this problem?

Comment: @CaveJohnson the assumption is that $f(z) = g'(z)$ where $g(z)$ is holomorphic (on the neighborhood of $|z| = 1$). So it reduces to show  $\int_0^{2\pi} f(e^{it}) e^{it} dt = -i \int_{|z| = 1} f(z) dz = -i g(z) |_1^1 = 0$

Answer (score 0):

You could consider: $$i\int_{0}^{2\pi}f(e^{it})e^{it}dt$$

Which is: $$\int_{C} f(z)dz$$

If f is holomorphic in $C$ (assuming that $C(t) = e^{it}, 0\le t \le2\pi$) then that integral is equal to $0$ by the residue theorem. Then: $$\int_{0}^{2\pi}f(e^{it})e^{it}dt = 0$$

because it's the same integral without the $i$ infront of it.

Comment: Alternatively, you can try to write a power series for $f$ to make this more rigorous.

Comment: in a deleted comment, someone proposed the real analytic way : by definition of $g(z)$ is holomorphic and $g'(z) = f(z)$, we have $f(e^{it}) e^{it} = -i\frac{\partial g(e^{it})}{\partial t}$ (easy to integrate with respect to $t$)

Comment: and your sentence "$f$ is holomorphic in $C$ and the residue theorem" is completely wrong (the Cauchy integral theorem is when $f(z)$ is holomorphic on a simply connected open containing the closed contour $C$, then $\int_C f(z) dz = 0$)